# Nextjs getStaticPaths url params build slash as %2F in vercel production environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am implementing nextjs dynamic route for my static documentation page.
It works perfectly in local, and it compiled successfully but it doesn't work with production URL.

I think my current code `getStaticPaths` url handling is something strange and producing strange `%2F` value in my URI as below. For example, the correct path has to be `example.com/docs/en-integrations-hello-test`.

[image]

In my [...slug].tsx

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    // get current path
    const myProdPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/')

    // grab all markdown files
    const docPaths = await glob(path.join(myProdPath, '**/*.md'))


    // For each filename, the slug is the filename without the .md extension
    const paths = await docPaths.map((docPath) => {
        const slug = docPath
            .replace(myProdPath, '')
            .replace('.md', '')

        console.log('this is slug:   ' + slug) < prints out corrently without %2F

        return { params: { slug: [slug] } }
    })

    // Return the possible paths
    return { paths, fallback: true }
}
```

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: @Ilir if you're still dealing with this, I just posted an answer you might find helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar issue in NextJS 13 using the App router in a catch-all route segment (folder named `[...slug]`)and the `generateStaticParams` function, which has a return signature similar to what you're showing here for `getStaticPaths`. I was trying to dynamically generate blog post slug paths based on a specific folder's contents, including subdirectories. Here is what I discovered and how I solved it.

### The Problem

The `next build` and `next dev` commands handle processing static parameters differently in some meaningful way. `next dev` returns the expected path including the slashes when getting the filenames using `globSync`:

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const filenames = globSync(
      [postsDirectory + '/**/*.md', postsDirectory + '/**/*.mdx'],
      { absolute: false, cwd: postsDirectory },
    )
  const markdownRegex = /\.md(x)?$/
  return filenames.map((filename) => ({
      slug: [filename.replace(markdownRegex, '')],
    }))
}
```

`generateStaticParams` in dev returns an array of parameters with slugs like these:

```
[
  { slug: [ 'article2' ] },
  { slug: [ 'article1' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023/newest-article' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023/directory/some-other-article' ] }
]
```

which are accessed via code like this:

```js
export default async function ArticleBySlug({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string[] }
}) {
  const filePath = path.join(postsDirectory, params.slug[0])

  // Do something with filePath to get article contents and build page...
```

However, when this code ran in `next build`, the resulting array looks more like this:

```
[
  { slug: [ 'article2' ] },
  { slug: [ 'article1' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023%2Fnewest-article' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023%2Fdirectory%2Fsome-other-article' ] }
]
```

Obviously, these filenames can't be found, and the build process crashes.

### The Solution

The answer was to make use of the fact that the `slug` parameter is expecting an array. Instead of returning an array of one string with slashes (`filename.replace(markdownRegex, '')`), we can return an actual array of route segments. The code now looks like this:

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const filenames = globSync(
      [postsDirectory + '/**/*.md', postsDirectory + '/**/*.mdx'],
      { absolute: false, cwd: postsDirectory },
    )
  const markdownRegex = /\.md(x)?$/
  return filenames.map((filename) => ({
      slug: filename.replace(markdownRegex, '').split(path.sep)
    }))
}
```

Now instead of returning an array containing one path string from which we remove the file extension, we are returning the results of using `string.split` on that path, splitting on `path.sep` which will be the operating system appropriate separator. This results in an array of segments in the `slug` property for each parameter, such as:

```
[
  { slug: [ 'article2' ] },
  { slug: [ 'article1' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023', 'newest-article' ] },
  { slug: [ '2023', 'directory', 'some-other-article' ] }
]
```

Then, instead of joining the string directly, we can use the spread operator to expand the array into `path.join`:

```js
export default async function ArticleBySlug({
  params,
}: {
  params: { slug: string[] }
}) {
  const filePath = path.join(postsDirectory, ...params.slug)

  // Do something with filePath to get article contents and build page...
```

This pattern works equally well in `next build` and `next dev` (using NextJS 13 and the app router). I assume if you are returning an array of strings as the `slug` parameter, it should work in the pages router with `getStaticPaths` as well.

Comment: Great solution, works with nextjs v12 too.

Comment: @lagerone great to know!

Comment: Wow, you saved my evening! Works at nexjs 14